# calculate column mean of a matrix - how to optimize?

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, numpy, python-multithreading

input:

```
[
[1,2,3,4,5],
[5,4,3,2,1],
[3,3,3,3,3]
]
```

output:

```
[3,3,3,3,3]
```

brute force solution:

```
def calculate_col_mean(matrix):
   mean = []
   num_row = len(matrix)
   num_col = len(matrix[0])
   result = [0] * num_col
   for i in range(num_row):
      for j in range(num_col):
          result[j] += matrix[i][j]

   for i in range(num_col):
       result[i] = result[i] / num_row

   return result
```

This works for small datasets. Imagine if our dataset is really big (1GB+++), how I can optimize this? Threading? How would I go about that?

PS: it took about 2 hours + running on 1GB data with the brute force approach.

Comment: What's `matrix`?  List of lists, 2d numpy array, dataframe, other?

Comment: Numpy has an inbuilt matrix.mean function. You may try that. [Numpy.matrix.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.mean.html)

Also, if even this seems slow in processing for larger sets, you may try including multiprocessing to your script

Comment: I doubt multithreading would do anything to help speed things up, as you would need split up the data first, which means you need to reallocate memory and create the whole threading infrastructure. That will probably take longer than doing simple arythmetic with a dataset.

Comment: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [5,4,3,2,1], [3,3,3,3,3]])

a.mean(axis=0)  # --- array([3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])

Comment: @mapf Multithreading will indeed not help at all but that's due to pythons global interpreter lock. Multiprocessing can be achieved with using numba. It is designed to automatically split the workload among the CPU cores.

Comment: @sunnytown thanks, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1],[3,3,3,3,3]])
column_mean = a.mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: this is still pretty slow... how does numpy optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

Highly advise using NumPy for something like this.

Go to your command line and activate your python environment.

```
pip install numpy
```

Open up Python at the command line or using Jupyter Notebooks (preferred)

```
import numpy as np
your_array = np.array([
[1,2,3,4,5],
[5,4,3,2,1],
[3,3,3,3,3]
])
```

0 in the mean(#) indicates the axis you'd like the mean performed on

```
column_averages = your_array.mean(0)

print(column_averages)
[3,3,3,3,3]
```

Comment: doesn't numpy basically use the the same algo as i wrote above? It's so slow.

Comment: numpy performs the loops in c compiled machine code, therefore approximately 100 times faster.